# How to make Google Earth stable in Ubuntu 14.04.2 64 bit?

Tags: google-earth

Does Google Earth run stable in Ubuntu 14.04.2 64 bit at your system?
I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 64 bit and Google Earth 64 bit runs unstable. It will not start properly. The start screen appears, but once the globe comes into view, the program stops and disappears from the screen. After repeatedly starting the program, it launches sometimes and the program comes with the globe and it is ready for use. But once I have typed a place to search and click on it, the program stops and disappears from the screen again. Who has Google Earth working stable in Ubuntu 14.04.2 64-bit? And did you have to do something special to make it run stable?

I downloaded the 64-bits .deb (for Debian/Ubuntu) from the site:
https://www.google.nl/intl/nl/earth/download/ge/agree.html

Best regards,
Wim van Hooff
The Netherlands

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Hi Hatterman, Maybe I have the answer for you.
I got the answer at a Dutch forum site.
You first have to install the lsb-core package from the Ubuntu Software center.
After that download and install the 64 bit deb file from Google Earth.
That was the solution for me.
Succes! Regards, Wim

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, please follow my advice below:

1. disable network access
2. the application will now open successfully
3. enable your network access and the program should now operate correctly.

You will need to repeat this each time you open the application.

Comment: It works! I have a 64-bit 14.04.3 system and tried the route installing the 32-bit (i386) libraries and then installing the 32-bit version of Earth 7.1. That didn't work (never opened after splash screen), so I switched to trying to install the 64-bit version. Not sure if this would work for the 32-bit install, too.

Comment: Google is THE biggest company in the world. Ubuntu is THE most used Linux flavor. HOW can't they cooperate?